# CORS support in OpenStack SWIFT

Tags: openstack-swift

How can I configure OpenStack SWIFT to send all the appropriate CORS headers in response to a client's OPTIONS request? I know about the crossdomain plugin to the SWIFT pipeline, but the documentation only says that something like the following is allowed:

```
[filter:crossdomain]
use = egg:swift#crossdomain
cross_domain_policy = <allow-access-from domain="xxx.yyy.com" />
```

It doesn't tell me how to specify the Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Max-Age, etc. headers.

Anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 3):

Despite very confusing documentation that led me to believe the container and object metadata of various (incorrect) forms were what I needed, it turned out that I needed to set the following two:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: xxx"
"Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Foo, X-Bar"
```

The various documentation that said to use X-Access-Control-Allow-Origin and X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Allow-Origin didn't work. I gleamed the above after looking through the code.

Comment: Where did you set these headers? On the container? On the POST request when you sent the object?

Comment: It works if you add the headers on the PUT request to create the container or when you call POST to update the headers of an existing container.

Answer (score 1):

**Openstack Swift**

You can set the following headers on a `Container` level only:

```
X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Allow-Origin
X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Max-Age
X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Allow-Headers
X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Expose-Headers
```

You can set a containers **CORS** permissions with :

```
curl -i -X POST https://swift.example.io/v1/AUTH_user/container \
           -H "X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" \
           -H 'X-Auth-Token: AUTH_xxx'
```

NOTE: This is how I implement it.

[Openstack Swift Docs](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/cors.html)

---

**Openstack User Guide**

You have many more options according to the current [Openstack User Guide](https://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/sdk-assign-cors-headers.html).  They haven't maintained the documentation consistently.

---

**UPDATED INFORMATION**

Information relating to the depreciation of `x-` specifications: https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/api-wg/guidelines/headers.html